# Compose Horizontal Pager always filling max size, verticalAligment not working

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm using [Google's Accompanist Horizontal Pager](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/), and I need the pager to wrap content size. For some reason it fills max size. Currently it's a child of constraint layout, however I tried putting it inside column with another having `Modifier.weight(1f)` - same result.
Also verticalAlignment doesn't work, child is centered.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdOMn.png); Green - pager, red - it's child.

Compose version : 1.0.5 ; Pager version : 0.21.3-beta

```
HorizontalPager(
            state = stickerBookState.pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(pager) {
                    top.linkTo(pagerNavigator.bottom, 16.dp)
                    linkTo(parent.start, parent.end)
                    height = Dimension.wrapContent // for whatever reason it's actual size if fillConstraints / fillMaxSize
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                }.background(PmColors.CompletedGreen),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top, // this one also doesn't seem to work
            count = model.pages.size,
        ) { pageIndex ->
            val pageData = model.pages[pageIndex]
            @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
            LazyVerticalGrid(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize()
                    .background(PmColors.AlertRed),
                cells = GridCells.Fixed(2)
            ) {
                items(pageData) { holderData ->
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(bottom = 24.dp)
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .wrapContentHeight(),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        // some composable
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: use fixed height dp

Comment: @KunalSharma, well, I can't really hardcode height in my case. But if there will be no other solution, I will probably go with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's bug that has been fixed in version [0.21.4](https://github.com/google/accompanist/releases/tag/v0.21.4):

> [Pager] Allow HorizontalPager to wrap content height and VerticalPager to wrap content width...

Modifying the code from their [sample](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/v0.21.4/sample/src/main/java/com/google/accompanist/sample/pager/HorizontalPagerBasicSample.kt) accomplishes the desired effect:

```
private fun Sample() {
Scaffold(
    ...
) {
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            ...
         HorizontalPager(
            ...
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top, //add this
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentHeight() //and this
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) { page ->
            ...
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: For someone has compose 1.0.5, the fix bug is available in accompanist 0.20.3

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top helped fix a jump / jank bug on page swipe for me, so thanks for the suggestion!